# Excel Checkbox delete when row is deleted

Tags: excel, checkbox

> I want too auto delete the checkboxes when i delete the row, is there a way to do this. I already tried asking ChatGPT but that didnt work I tried some scripts i found here but still doesnt work. If anyone could help me outhere that would be greatly appreciate.

> ```
> I expected the scripts that i tried to work
> ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add sample data and your current attempt to fix the issue
2. Make sure the names of the checkboxes are shown